# perl regex matching issue

Tags: perl

I am having a problem in my RegEx matching.

```
my $line = 'Line no. : 8 : 8 : <ENAMEX TYPE="GENE">'
  . 'CRP</ENAMEX> : directly inhibits : endothelial cell nitric'
  . 'oxide <ENAMEX TYPE="GENE">facs</ENAMEX>'
  . '<ENAMEX TYPE="GENE">crp</ENAMEX>:inhibit:endothelial'
  . 'cell nitric oxide :Confidence Score 0.9017396427774064';

$line =~ /(.+)(\<ENAMEX TYPE\=\"GENE\"\>)(.+)(\<\/ENAMEX\>) (.+)(\<ENAMEX TYPE\=\"GENE\"\>)(.+)(\<\/ENAMEX\>)(.+)/;

print "$3 ---$5 ---$7\n";
```

And the Output is :

```
CRP ---: directly inhibits : endothelial cell nitric oxide <ENAMEX TYPE="GENE">facs</ENAMEX> ---
```

Problem :

What I want is to extract the 3 things using the regex . The output should have been something like 
CRP ---: directly inhibits : endothelial cell nitric oxide  --- facs;

Please do tell me what is the problem as $2 is printing anything after the first block and the regex isn't matching the second part.
Thanks

Comment: Try to use a nongreedy quantifiers, i.e. replace `.+` with `.+?`. See [`perlretut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) for more information

Comment: YUp That works. Thanks a million

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get your desired matches, you need to use a nongreedy quantifiers, i.e. replace `.+` with `.+?`, in your regex:

```
$line =~ /(.+?)(\<ENAMEX[ ]TYPE\=\"GENE\"\>)(.+?)(\<\/ENAMEX\>)[ ]
      (.+?)(\<ENAMEX[ ]TYPE\=\"GENE\"\>)(.+?)(\<\/ENAMEX\>)(.+?)/x;
```

According to [`perlretut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html):

> Sometimes greed is not good. At times, we would like quantifiers to
> match a minimal piece of string, rather than a maximal piece. For this
> purpose, Larry Wall created the minimal match or non-greedy
> quantifiers ?? , *? , +?, and {}?. These are the usual quantifiers
> with a ? appended to them. They have the following meanings:
>
> [...]
>
> - a+? means: match 'a' 1 or more times, i.e., at least once, but as few times as possible

Comment: @ary If this answer solved you problem, consider accepting it. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)